# React text dropdown toggle (toggles all)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dropdown

I am trying to make a small text dropdown. When you click on the heading text, the p tag will show. It is working, but.. it is toggling all of them, when I only click on of them. I have multiple "li" tags with text and the function. So I am not looping anything

```
const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false)

  const toggleText = () => {
    setActive(!isActive)
  } 


  <li>
              <h2 onClick={toggleText}>Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet</h2>

              {isActive && (
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut
                  reprehenderit explicabo laudantium quas, minus recusandae
                  quibusdam dolorem dolorum possimus natus quod nam, et labore
                  iste eos? Ducimus optio dolor soluta!
                </p>
              )}
              <div onClick={toggleText} className='dropDown__plus'>
                {!isActive ? (
                  <img src={plusIcon} alt='Plus icon' />
                ) : (
                  <img src={minusIcon} alt='Minus Icon' />
                )}
              </div>
            </li>
```

Comment: It's not shown in your code/question, but I suppose you are using some kind of loop or map to generate the markup? In that case, you need to store the active state for _each_ entry.

Comment: Hey, I've just edited the post, to make it more clear - sorry.

Comment: Are you sharing the `isActive` state across multiple elements? Do you have multiple `<li>` blocks in the same component? In one way or another, you have a scoping issue and you're recycling the state in your rendering function.

Comment: Yes I am sharing the isActive across multiple elements. The <li> block looks the  9 others I have. And when I toggle of them, everyone shows. How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to use a separate `isActive` state for each pair. I would advise you abstract this into a separate component: the parent (i.e. the one you have now) component shouldn't be responsible for tracking these states anyway, and should be delegated to the inner component

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean, sorry. Do you have a code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question and the comments, you are reusing the `isActive` state across multiple elements in the same component, which means that each element does not have its *own* `isActive` state: they all share the same state globally.

You can create a child component that handles the state exclusively, while allowing it to receive contents in the form of `props`, e.g. for the heading and content:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function MyComponent(props) {
  const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);

  const toggleText = () => {
    setActive(!isActive);
  };

  return (
    <li>
      <h2 onClick={toggleText}>{props.heading}</h2>

      {isActive && props.content}
      <button type="button" onClick={toggleText} className="dropDown__plus">
        {!isActive ? <>+</> : <>-</>}
      </button>
    </li>
  );
}
```

Then, in your original parent component it's just a matter of using `<MyComponent>` to handle all your `<li>` entries:

```
<ul>
  <MyComponent
    heading="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    content={<p>Some text here</p>}
  />
  <MyComponent
    heading="Foo bar"
    content={<p>More foo bar content</p>}
  />
  <MyComponent
    heading="Last header"
    content={<p>C'est la vie</p>}
  />
</ul>
```

You can see a proof-of-concept example here:

[image: Edit aged-field-nj1z6]